# Why a comment could be deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, community-user, community-moderation

A few days ago I asked [a question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/382189/301671) on Ask Different and a user answered me. another user who is one of Ask Different moderators, leave [an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382210/301671) but based on the community rights, I believe his post was not an answer, it could be a comment. so I leave a downvote and I put the *not an answer* flag. After all, I leave a comment. but yesterday I saw my comment was deleted.

Weird, because the moderator who posted and I downvoted him, told me I didn't leave an action.

I'm shocked, I was not rude. I just act as community rights. so why my comment was deleted? I just know to learn how the community works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general comments are considered to be temporary information which can (and sometimes will) get deleted once the objective/purposed of it is reached.

The purpose of comments as such is documented in the [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

PS: I handled the flag you left on the post. If you don‘t consider an answer to be helpful, please downvote instead of flagging.

Comment: Thanks, Dear nohillside, for your exact answer. I got I did wrong, but still, I believe deleting a comment is not fair. you could write to me about my faults and reject my flag. how ever, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @AmerllicA You did nothing wrong, both commenting and flagging are features to be used :-) But your comment was addressed to the author of the post who obviously did read it. There was no need to keep it around longer.

Comment: So, Do you delete all comments which are seen by the post author? I think you discriminate between formal users and moderator users.

Comment: @AmerllicA As I said both in the answer and in the comment: Comments which have served their purpose are candidates for deletion. In the specific case I deleted both your comment and the reply comment by the author because keeping them doesn't add value to the site any longer.

Comment: @AmerllicA And just for reference: in the last 30 days we deleted about 300 comments overall, some of them due to comment flags, most others because there were no longer required. There is no dedicated task to delete old comments though, so you will easily find a lot of comments which are outdated.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to set aside all the specifics of the flag and who handled it other than I didn’t handle the flag on my answer.

- Answer: they explain how to solve a problem
- Comments: they seek to clarify the question

In this case, i think your problem was clear and wanted to propose you getting your sound in a way that doesn’t violate the terms of the App Store license.

I love technical discussions how to reverse engineer a program but don’t see it as a proper general answer so I wanted to propose another way for you to get your sound.

How is that not an answer?

Comment: Thanks for your good answer, you manner should be our model, we should learn to be like you as manner. thanks.